# JSON for dynamic object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am getting a list of countries along the count of partners in each country using the following linq query

```
Partners.GroupBy(
    x => x.Country, x => x.DisplayName, (key, g) =>
    new Groups{ country = key, partners = g.Count() }
);
```

now I want to send this information in a WebAPI response and the format must be like the following as the consumer application is already developed by an outsourced company.

```
"idIndex": {
    "30": 0,
    "47": 1,
    "49": 2
}
```

In the above 30,47 and 49 is the number of partners in each country and 0,1,2 are their indexes.

Regards,
Zafar

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem: I want the JSON response in the format mentioned.

Comment: But the above is not valid JSON...

Comment: @Zafar can you debug it and store the result in a variable, which will define the diff beteen what you getting and what you want

Comment: "In the above 30,47 and 49 is the number of partners in each country and 0,1,2 are their indexes." Shouldn't your JSON format be the other way around? What if two countries have the same number of partners?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem: that answers my question I guess, am not much familiar with JSON formats. Thanks

Comment: @Rotem, the consumer application is already made and I am stuck with the formats and anything they required, don't have much choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary of the results of `GroupBy`:

```
Partners.GroupBy(
    x => x.Country, x => x.DisplayName)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

Comment: This. You can convert the dictionary to a JSON blob which will show whatever values the dictionary holds.